# error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hta

i am writing an hta application and am using javascript. It says `there should be a ";" at line one char 10`. This is the code:

```
Function SetSize()
{
 window.resizeTo(400,400);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `Function` keyword, use lower case `function`.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a case sensitive language; update as follows:

```
function SetSize()
{
 window.resizeTo(400, 400);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function has to be written in lower case

```
function SetSize()
{
  window.resizeTo(400,400);
}
```

there are also some [conventions by Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) that declare that function names should be in lower case too and the braces should be placed in the same line of the function head.

```
function setSize() {
  window.resizeTo(400,400);
}
```

this is not needed to run the code error free but it's a convention almost every javascript programer uses and helps writing readable code for everyone.

Comment: Thanks did not know that function had to be lower case